# PHP: cannot redeclare class

Tags: php, class

So I have 3 classes in this situation.

```
Connection.php
Engineer.php
Status.php
```

Both Engineer and Status classes actually use connection. Hasn't been a problem but now that I'm using both classes in a page I'm getting

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Connection
```

Is there a way round this? In both classes I need db access from the connection class.

Thanks,

Jonesy

Answer (score 11, accepted):

instead of using include() use require_once() for importing Connection.php into Engineer.php and Status.php.

Answer (score 3):

You can always:

```
if(  !class_exists('Connection') ) {
    include('Connection.php');
}
```

or just use `include_once`([link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)) or `require_once` ([link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)) or [autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) mechanism

Answer (score 2):

Use require_once() rather than require().

Or alternatively, use [autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php), which saves you having to specify it loads of times.

I suspect the autoload functionality would be the best thing for you, assuming you're using a new-enough version of PHP (it requires 5.3).

Answer (score 1):

Use require_once.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using an unsafe class file inclusion method, such as `require` or `include`.

Try using `include_once` or `require_once`.

Answer (score 1):

well, how are you including the Connection.php? try using `require_once`.