# Database class conflicts with other classess

Tags: php, oop, class, declaration, extends

I have been in toruble with kind of conflict issue. There is a Database Class which contains connection, update, delete, insert, fetch methods and also there is User Class which extends Database Class.

```
class User extends Database {...}
```

Problem is, when I initialize the Database class and User Class at the same time in "index.php", I get an fatal error which says "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Database".

```
include "database.class.php";
include "user.class.php;
$db = new Database;
$db->connect();
```

So, I am aware of initializing database class twice, but how can prevent not to happen? P.S.: I can use Database class in other new classes.

Comment: `require_once("database.class.php");` instead of `include` wherever you are including it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: cannot redeclare class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769909/php-cannot-redeclare-class)

Comment: Just to get it right: Users are databases?! Oo

Comment: It doesnt work Michael. There is still same error unfortunately.

Comment: User Class is a class @KingCrunch.

Comment: You have to use require_once('database.class.php') instead of include *wherever* you are using it. You can't just replace it in one spot, otherwise the second attempt to include will have this error.

Comment: Thanks all of you. It is normally working..(by using require_once).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OOP the `extends` means "is a". What you have written there says: "User is a Database". Which is certifiably bonkers.

Instead of extending the database class, you should be injecting it into constructor of `User` instance:

```
$database = new Database(...);
$database->connect();
$user = new User( $database );
```

Always [favor composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

As for all that `require_once` mess .. just learn how to use [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php).

Comment: Can you give an example how am I gonna use? how should constructor of user class supposed to be? This usage is kind of strange to me.

Comment: @GncArt , constructor of any class should be only assigning values to local variables. In a well written object oriented code, constructors don't do any "work".

Comment: @GncArt , if you really want to learn more about OOP, you should watch few lectures on subject. If you scroll to "OOP beyond classes" part of [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846220/php-oop-core-framework/9855170#9855170), there will be a list of video on the subject. Watch them. You will learn a lot from them .. I sure did.

Answer (score 1):

Change the two "includes" you have for "require_once", as Michael said:

```
require_once "database.class.php";
require_once "user.class.php";
$db = new Database;
$db->connect();
```

Besides, if within the file "user.class.php" you are including the file "database.class.php", change it to "require_once" too.

I hope it helped!